# Installing mercurial on SME server

Tags: installation, mercurial

There doesn't appear to be a yum package, so whats the best way to install mercurial on SME server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial can be found in the [EPEL repository](http://wiki.contribs.org/Epel) for derivatives of EL4 and EL5, which SME Server is.